# JUnit tests pass in Eclipse but fail in Maven Surefire

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, surefire, spring-test

I have written some JUnit tests using JUnit 4 and spring-test libraries. When I run the tests inside Eclipse then run fine and pass. But when I run them using Maven (during the build process), they fail giving a spring related error. I am not sure what is causing the problem, JUnit, Surefire or Spring. Here is my test code, spring configuration and the exception that I get from Maven:

*PersonServiceTest.java*

```
package com.xyz.person.test;

import static com.xyz.person.util.FjUtil.toFjList;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.xyz.person.bo.Person;
import com.xyz.person.bs.PersonService;

import fj.Effect;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:personservice-test.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
public class PersonServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService service;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testCreatePerson() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("abhinav");
        service.createPerson(person);

        assertNotNull(person.getId());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testFindPersons() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("abhinav");
        service.createPerson(person);

        List<Person> persons = service.findPersons("abhinav");
        toFjList(persons).foreach(new Effect<Person>() {
            public void e(final Person p) {
                assertEquals("abhinav", p.getName());
            }});
    }

}
```

*personservice-test.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/personservice.xml" />

    <bean id="datasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:InMemoryDatabase;create=true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PersonService" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" />
                <entry key="javax.persistence.transactionType" value="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        proxy-target-class="false" />

    <bean id="beanMapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
        <property name="mappingFiles">
            <list>
                <value>personservice-mappings.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

*Exception in Maven*

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.xyz.person.test.PersonServiceTest
23:18:51,250  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Warning: 10000, SQLState: 01J01
23:18:51,281  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Database 'InMemoryDatabase' not created, connection made to existing database instead.
23:18:52,937  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Warning: 10000, SQLState: 01J01
23:18:52,937  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Database 'InMemoryDatabase' not created, connection made to existing database instead.
23:18:52,953  WARN TestContextManager:429 - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@359a359a] to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void com.xyz.person.test.PersonServiceTest.testCreatePerson()], instance [com.xyz.person.test.PersonServiceTest@1bc81bc8], exception [org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single JpaTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether JPA or JDBC access.]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@3f563f56] bound to thread [main]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:199)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(JpaTransactionManager.java:489)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1011)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:804)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:515)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:290)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:183)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:426)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:90)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:102)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
23:18:53,078  WARN TestContextManager:377 - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@359a359a] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void com.xyz.person.test.PersonServiceTest.testFindPersons()] for test instance [com.xyz.person.test.PersonServiceTest@79f279f2]
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single JpaTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether JPA or JDBC access.
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:304)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:507)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.startNewTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:269)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:162)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:374)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:102)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.625 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error:
  testCreatePerson(com.xyz.person.test.PersonServiceTest)
  testCreatePerson(com.xyz.person.test.PersonServiceTest)
  testFindPersons(com.xyz.person.test.PersonServiceTest)

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: do you have any special configuration of the surefire plugin in your POM?

Comment: @matt I don't have any configuration for surefire in my pom

Comment: I came to this article because I had the same problem, but in my case I used another solution. After enabling DEBUG logs on my tests, I found out that Spring Framework was looking at an old MongoDB database name, and this name was set in an old version of a jar created by another project on my workspace (although it was built several times with the new name). Some Maven Clen + deleting the libraries on my .m2 followed by Maven Install of all those projects solved the problem. Although there was no reason for the project to look at an old jar (it was cached somewhere, unfortunately)

Answer (score 136):

I had the same problem (JUnit tests failed in Maven Surefire but passed in Eclipse) and managed to solve it by setting **forkMode** to **always** in the maven surefire configuration in pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12</version>
  <configuration>
    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Surefire parameters: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

**Edit (January 2014):**

As [Peter Perháč](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81520/peter-perhac) pointed out, the forkMode parameter is deprecated since Surefire 2.14. Beginning from Surefire 2.14 use this instead:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.16</version>
  <configuration>
    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For more information see [Fork Options and Parallel Test Execution](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)

Comment: Thank yoU! Fixed the issue for me. Any idea why?

Comment: Good to hear. In my case the problem was very likely that a configuration file read by the JUnit test stayed in the memory, corrupting the result of a subsequent test. When forkMode is set to true, each test class is executed completely indenpendently of the other guaranteeing that the tests are executed without side effects.

Comment: just tried this using surefire 2.16 and got: "The parameter forkMode is deprecated since version 2.14. Use forkCount and reuseForks instead." so beware this only works on pre-2.14

Comment: Thanks, answser modified accordingly.

Comment: You can most likely use a higher fork count, the importance here is that forks aren't reused and a single fork will make package builds take a very long time.

Comment: Plus one for updating your answer two years later

Comment: Still fixing problems in 2017. If only we understood why!

Comment: My understanding is that some JUnit parameters "leak" to other tests. Maybe some test settings are saved across the tests because of how the test classes are implemented internally or because of how JUnit works. Depending on the execution order of the tests some subsequent test may fail, if the execution context is not reset between tests, which the reuseForks setting accomplishes.

Comment: Hello from mid 2019. Encountered this issue with spring version 1.5.12.RELEASE with the same context testing approach that I've used in latest spring 2+ versions. Probably latest versions of Spring / Mockito / JUnit resolved this issue.

Comment: @SandySimonton Your suggestion about a higher fork count seems good to speed up the tests. Any idea what a sensible value should be?

Comment: @SteveChambers I'm a little late here, but 1 per cpu core I think is reasonable (forkCount=1C) - it does depend on the build machine of course.

Answer (score 11):

I suddenly experienced this error, and the solution for me was to disable to run tests in parallel.

Your milage may vary, since I could lower number of failing tests by configuring surefire to run parallel tests by ´classes´.:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

As I wrote first, this was not enough for my test suite, so I completely disabled parallel by removing the `<configuration>` section.

Answer (score 8):

Test execution result different from `JUnit run` and from `maven install` seems to be symptom for several problems.

Disabling thread reusing test execution did also get rid of the symptom in our case, but the impression that the code was not thread-safe was still strong.

In our case the difference was due to the presence of a bean that modified the test behaviour. Running just the JUnit test would result fine, but running the project `install` target would result in a failed test case. Since it was the test case under development, it was immediately suspicious.

It resulted that another test case was instantiating a bean through Spring that would survive until the execution of the new test case. The bean presence was modifying the behaviour of some classes and producing the failed result.

The solution in our case was getting rid of the bean, which was not needed in the first place (yet another prize from the *copy+paste* gun).

I suggest everybody with this symptom to investigate what the root cause is. Disabling thread reuse in test execution might only hide it.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, the annotation `@Autowired` in the test code did not work under using the Maven command line while it worked fine in Eclipse. I just update my JUnit version from 4.4 to 4.9 and the problem was solved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the similar problem, but with IntelliJ IDEA + Maven + TestNG + spring-test. (**spring-test** is essential of course :) )
It was fixed when I've change config of **maven-surefire-plugin** to disable run tests in parallel. Like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${maven.test.skip}</skipTests>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
        <!--<parallel>methods</parallel>-->
        <!-- to skip integration tests -->
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/IT*Test.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/integration/*Test.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${maven.integration-test.skip}</skipTests>
                <!-- Make sure to include this part, since otherwise it is excluding Integration tests -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>none</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/IT*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/integration/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't exactly apply to your situation, but I had the same thing -- tests that would pass in Eclipse failed when the test goal from Maven was run.

It turned out to be a test earlier in my suite, *in a different package*.  This took me a week to solve!

An earlier test was testing some Logback classes, and created a Logback context from a config file.

The later test was testing a subclass of Spring's SimpleRestTemplate, and somehow, the earlier Logback context was held, with DEBUG on.  This caused extra calls to be made in RestTemplate to log HttpStatus, etc.

It's another thing to check if one ever gets into this situation. I fixed my problem by injecting some Mocks into my Logback test class, so that no real Logback contexts were created.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I hit similar problem where default maven project had a traditional test case autogenerated (which I ignored) whereas I was using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner for my new test cases. Adding SpringJUnit4ClassRunner annotation to autogenerated test solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but the problem for me was that Java assertions (e.g. assert(num > 0)) were not enabled for Eclipse, but were enabled when running maven.

Therefore running the jUnit tests from Eclipse did not catch trigger the assertion error.

This is made clear when using jUnit 4.11 (as opposed to the older version I was using) because it prints out the assertion error, e.g.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at com.company.sdk.components.schema.views.impl.InputViewHandler.<init>(InputViewHandler.java:26)
    at test.com.company.sdk.util.TestSchemaExtractor$MockInputViewHandler.<init>(TestSchemaExtractor.java:31)
    at test.com.company.sdk.util.TestSchemaExtractor.testCreateViewToFieldsMap(TestSchemaExtractor.java:48)
```

Comment: in this case, this link is relevant: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/java.lang.AssertionError+When+Sending+Mail+Via+SMTP

Comment: ...and in case of gradle, add this: test {
   enableAssertions = false
   ignoreFailures = true
}

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a different cause and therefore different solution.  In my case, I actually had an error where a singleton object was having a member variable modified in a non-threadsafe way.  In this case, following the accepted answers and circumventing the parallel testing would only hide the error that was actually revealed by the test.  My solution, of course, is to fix the design so that I don't have this bad behavior in my code.

Answer (score 2):

[I am not sure that this is an answer to the original question, since the stacktrace here looks slightly different, but it may be useful to others.]

You can get tests failing in Surefire when you are also running Cobertura (to get code coverage reports).  This is because Cobertura requires proxies (to measure code use) and there is some kind of conflict between those and Spring proxies.  This *only* occurs when Spring uses cglib2, which would be the case if, for example, you have `proxy-target-class="true"`, or if you have an object that is being proxied that does not implement interfaces.

The normal fix to this is to add an interface.  So, for example, DAOs should be interfaces, implemented by a DAOImpl class.  If you autowire on the interface, everything will work fine (because cglib2 is no longer required; a simpler JDK proxy to the interface can be used instead and Cobertura works fine with this).

However, you cannot use interfaces with annotated controllers (you will get a runtime error when trying to use the controller in a servlet) - I do not have a solution for Cobertura + Spring tests that autowire controllers.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem: JUnit tests failed in Maven Surefire but passed in Eclipse when I used JUnit library version 4.11.0 from SpringSource Bundle Repository. Particulary:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.org.junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I replaced it with following JUnit library version 4.11 and everything works fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This did the trick for me.  My tests ran immediately when I ran Maven from the command line.  In Eclipse, however, I had to close and re-open the project before the unit tests would run in the JUnit window.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today testing a method that converted an object that contained a `Map` to a JSON string. I assume Eclipse and the Maven surefire plugin were using different JREs which had different implementations of `HashMap` ordering or something, which caused the tests run through Eclipse to pass and the tests run through surefire to fail (`assertEquals` failed). The easiest solution was to use an implementation of Map that had reliable ordering.

Answer (score 1):

This has helped me in troubleshooting my problem. I had a similar symptoms in that maven would fail however running junit tests runs fine.

As it turns out my parent pom.xml contains the following definition:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.9</version>
      <configuration>
        <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Xverify:none</argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

And in my project I override it to remove the argLine:

```
    <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
            <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
            <argLine combine.self="override"></argLine>
          </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Hopefully this will help someone in troubleshooting surefire plugin.

Comment: "[`<forkMode>` **DEPRECATED** since version 2.14. Use `forkCount` and `reuseForks` instead.](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkMode)"

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was a bug in the code. The test relied on a certain order of elements in a `HashSet`, which turned out to be different when run either in Eclipse or in Maven Surefire.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I ran my tests disabling the reuse of forks like this

```
mvn clean test -DreuseForks=false
```

and the problem disappeared.
The downside is that the overall test execution time will be longer, that's why you may want to do this from the command line only if necessary

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject a DataSource in the JpaTransactionManager since the EntityManagerFactory already has a datasource. Try the following:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: The tests fail (with errors) in Eclipse if I remove the datasource from the transactionManager bean.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when tests pass in eclipse and fail with maven it is a classpath issue because it is the main difference between the two.

So you can check the classpath with maven -X test and check the classpath of eclipse via the menus or in the .classpath file in the root of your project.

Are you sure for example that personservice-test.xml is in the classpath ?

Comment: Yes, because I can see the INFO logs from Spring context loading in the console during the maven test run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution for me was to allow Maven to handle all dependencies, including to local jars. I used Maven for online dependencies, and configured build path manually for local dependencies.
Thus, Maven was not aware of the dependencies I configured manually.

I used this solution to install the local jar dependencies into Maven:

[How to add local jar files in maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project)

Answer (score 0):

Tests might interfere with each other.

Check this by running only a single test by Maven:

```
mvn -Dtest=PersonServiceTest#testCreatePerson clean test
```

or by setting Surfire plugin's config and then run all tests by `mvn clean test`:

```
<configuration>
  <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
</configuration>
```

If the commands succeed, then you should look for tests affecting your test.
In my case the issue was caused by creation of MockStatic outside of try-with-resources block in another test.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, inside @Before method, an object was created and later used in other tests but for some reason when running in mvn install, the object comes as null, so I explicitly created this object in each of the test and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

It is most likely that your configuration files are in *src/main/resources*, while they must be under *src/test/resources* to work properly under maven.

https://cwiki.apache.org/UIMA/differences-between-running-unit-tests-in-eclipse-and-in-maven.html

I'm replying this after two years 'cause I couldn't find this answer here and I think it is the right one.

Comment: No, it's the other way around. `src/main/resources` is visible to tests, but `src/test/resources` isn't visible to production code.

Comment: the link you added is talking about dependencies *between* projects, not within main/test in the same project