# Maven surefire tests failing in Spring framework project

Tags: spring, maven, junit, surefire

Maven is unable to successfully run my JUnit tests though they are being run without any problem on my Eclipse. I'm unable to solve it from the debug messages.

It is probably something to do with the Spring config because my other JUnit tests not relying on Spring are working fine.

[Adding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825309/640378) the surefire plugin forkMode as Always didn't work either.

#### Maven output

> > mvn install ... ... [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ AppServer --- [INFO] Surefire report directory:
> >     C:..\surefire-reports
>
> Running com.ws.impl.BrowserServiceImplTest Tests run: 2, Failures: 2,
>   Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec <<< FAILURE!
>
> Failed tests:   com.ws.impl.BrowserServiceImplTest.testGetStatuses()
>   com.ws.impl.BrowserServiceImplTest.testGetSellers()

#### Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-context.xml")
public class BrowserServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private BrowserServiceImpl browserServiceImpl;

    @Test
    public void testGetStatuses() {
        // test code
    }
        // more code
}
```

#### Surefire report

```
<failure type="java.lang.NullPointerException">java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ws.impl.BrowserServiceImplTest.testGetStatuses(BrowserServiceImplTest.java:48)
</failure>
```

### Edit

Lines 48-49

```
List<String> statuses = browserServiceImpl.getStatuses();
assertEquals(12, statuses.size());
```

### Edit 2

test-context.xml

```
<bean id="browserSvc" class="com.ws.impl.BrowserServiceImpl">
    <property name="filterOptionsService" ref="filterOptionsService" />
</bean>
```

BrowserServiceImpl.java

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://abc.def.com", portName = "BrowserPort", serviceName = "BrowserService")
public class BrowserServiceImpl implements BrowserService {

    private FilterOptionsService filterOptionsService;

        // more code
}
```

Comment: It would probly help if you showed us line 48 of BrowserServiceImplTest

Comment: If it is your spring object, then yes, it's obviously not loading your spring config.

Comment: @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/application-context.xml"})

Comment: Yeah, looks like your bean isn't getting autoLoaded.  You say the same test runs fine though from within eclipse?

Comment: @UncleIroh Yes, it runs fine from within eclipse.

Comment: Did you try replacing "classpath:test-context.xml" with "/test-context.xml"?

Comment: @UncleIroh It fails with both `@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")`, `@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/test-context.xml"})`

Comment: Your test-context.xml probably don't define a bean for `BrowserServiceImpl` . Note that usually the field is an interface (i.e. probably `BrowserService`). Why is it working in eclipse ??? no idea... maybe a bug in eclipse.

Comment: @ben75 see Edit 2. I do have a bean for BrowserServiceImpl.

Comment: Where does `test-context.xml` reside? Since you're using Maven, it must reside in `src/test/resources/test-context.xml`; otherwise, it will not be visible as a classpath resource for your tests when running the Maven build.

Comment: @SamBrannen Yes, it resides in `src/test/resources/`

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? Also, have you verified that the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is actually being used to run the test (e.g., via log output)?