# Attribute "parallel" with value "none" must have a value from the list "false methods tests classes instances "

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created maven project using selenium webdriver in these I have integrate the testng, but when I validate my maven project it displayed **"Attribute "parallel" with value "none" must have a value from the list "false methods tests classes instances"** in `testng-failed.xml` and in `testng.xml`.

Can anyone please help me to resolved this problem.

**testng-failed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Failed suite [Gmail]" parallel="none">
  <test name="GmailLoginTest(failed)" parallel="none">
    <classes>
      <class name="gmailTestcc.LoginTest">
        <methods>
          <include name="setUp"/>
          <include name="mainAndGmailDashboardTest"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- gmailTestcc.LoginTest -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- GmailLoginTest(failed) -->
</suite> <!-- Failed suite [Gmail] -->
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Gmail" parallel="none">
  <test name="GmailLoginTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="gmailTestcc.LoginTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- GmailLoginTest -->
</suite> <!-- Gmail -->
```

Comment: Can you please be specific what you want to achieve? Why don't you remove the parallel = "none" from your XML?

Comment: @4M01 Actually at the validating a project it displayed this error. So, I don't understand why it come. can you please let what the exact problem is?
Ans this issue has been fixed now.

Comment: Are you using -maven-surefire-plugin ?

Comment: @4M01 Yes I am using it.

Comment: I think there is an issue while using both together. You need make changes in POM - forkMode to always in the maven surefire

Comment: @4M01 Can you please let me know how it is? or share some reference URL? Actually I am beginner in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93654/discussion-between-user1989314-and-4m01).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365628/junit-tests-pass-in-eclipse-but-fail-in-maven-surefire

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, I think this problem was caused by this attribute in your testng.xml "**parallel="none"**". Could you change it to false to have a try?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to Maven, it relates to TestNG itself, you can try solving it either by replacing

```
parallel="none" by parallel="false"
```

or changing your TestNG version from (6.9.10) to (6.9.9) because this issue is related to TestNg version 6.9.10.

Please note that if you used the second solution (which is better), you have to change

```
parallel="none" by parallel="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** Attribute "parallel" with value "none" must have a value from the list "false methods tests classes instances throws by the testNG if parallel execution is not handling properly in test suite :

if want to handle test execution parallel then use below xml suite:

```
<suite name="regression" parallel="test" threadcount="10">
```

Otherwise don't use parallel attribute in test suite