# Spring data rest customization working in eclipse test cases but not by maven surefire

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Hi I am having a strange issue I am using spring data rest with spring boot for my rest api . Also I am doing some customization via jackson modules to add a custom BeanSerializerModifier to perform some filtering opertaions.The weird part is the beanserializer works fine while using eclipse test cases which is the below method

```
public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
     List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties){
```

is applied to each class entity as well as spring data rest wrappers like PagedResources and HalLinks .But when I run the same via maven test cases it doesn't get applied (or gets skipped) on entity classes not sure why ?

the code how I am registering jackson modules is as below

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonCustomizations {

    private @Autowired FilteringSerializerModifier serializerModifier;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void configeJackson(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
        jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.modules(new HfdServicesModule());
    }

    /*
     * @Autowired CustomIntrospector customIntrospector;
     */

  /*  public @Bean Module hfServicesModule() {

        return new HfServicesModule();
    }*/

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class HfdServicesModule extends SimpleModule {
        public HfServicesModule() {
            setSerializerModifier(serializerModifier);

        }

        @Override
        public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {

            super.setupModule(context);
        }
}
```

Let me know what I am missing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi finally figured out that the issue is with maven reuseFork .The answer here helped me in understanding the same [JUnit tests pass in Eclipse but fail in Maven Surefire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365628/junit-tests-pass-in-eclipse-but-fail-in-maven-surefire)

so for the fix I had to just put this in the maven surefore plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
</configuration>
```

Hope it Helps ..