# Maven - execute single test class in a separate, multithreaded jvm process

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing

**Context:**
My project has around a thousand test methods.
I am executing `mvn test` with `reuseForks=true` that causes JVM processes to be reused across test classes. This works for most of my test classes, however, one class has to be executed in a separate JVM process, multithreaded.
Specifying `reuseForks=false` obviously causes multiple process termination and creation operations that take simply too much time.

**Question:**
Is it possible to execute `mvn test` with `reuseForks=false` and `parallel=method` on a single test class? Leaving all other classes with `reuseForks=true` and no parallel execution?

Comment: Why does your code need such thing? A Unit Test ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes. These are unit tests. Sharing processes in execution results in some test failures since configuration files are cached. I experience an issue similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365628/junit-tests-pass-in-eclipse-but-fail-in-maven-surefire

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible to be configured in the pom.

As a workaround you can execute `mvn test` twice. First run all of the tests except the special one. Second run the special test. You can place this complexity in utility shell script.