# Tests Run fine in Eclipse but failed in mvn command

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

The test is very very simple test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnitTestMyCode {

  @InjectMocks
  private MyClass resource;

  @Mock
  private DependentBean bean;

  @Test
  public void test1() throws Exception {
    boolean ss = true;
    assertThat(ss).isTrue();
}
```

**Error**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Field 'resource' annotated with @InjectMocks is null.
Please make sure the instance is created *before* MockitoAnnotations.initMocks();
Example of correct usage:
   class SomeTest {
      @InjectMocks private Foo foo = new Foo();

      @Before public void setUp() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMock(this);

    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.withBefores(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
```

Surefire plugin Config

```
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest*.java</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*UnitTest*.java</include>
              </includes>
              <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>  
          <includes>
                <include>**/*UnitTest*.java</include>
          </includes>            
          <skip>false</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

I have followed the steps at this [JUnit tests pass in Eclipse but fail in Maven Surefire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365628/junit-tests-pass-in-eclipse-but-fail-in-maven-surefire)
But no luck.

Any help here.

Comment: Have you tried what the error suggested you to do ?

Comment: Maven is always right. Can you show your mockito dependency ?

Comment: You are using an extreme old version of maven-surefire-plugin. Furthermore why are you doing so much configuration. Follow the naming conventions makes life easier... And yes the whole pom file is a good idea...

Comment: i facing this issue even with mockito verison 3.0.0. any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Mockito solved the issue

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```